# Login SQL Server without having password with mapping an environment variable to password

Tags: sql-server, authentication, environment-variables

I want to define password in environment variable inside windows and instead of password give users the environment variable to login.

Do we have such thing in SQL Server? And how they can login with environment variable through SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The SQL Client drivers won't pick up credentials from environment variables.  If you are writing an application you can do that and pass them to the driver.  But there's no way, say, to cause SSMS to pick up credentials from the environment.

On Windows your users should connect using Windows Auth, using their own identity.  Alternatively you can override the users' Windows identity with credentials stored in the Windows Credential Store, or provided while launching the process with `runas` to impersonant another user locally and on the network, or `runas /netonly` to only use the provided credentials with network authentication (NTLM).